# Why the control can not be find by byId?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get the `sap.m.Input` control via `byId` call as following:

[image]

As you can see above, I am calling:

```
this.byId("CharInput-001-ZPM_TEST_01-ZPM_TEST_5")
```

with the right `id` and get **undefined**. What am I doing wrong?

**Hint:** The `id` was **auto generated** at the runtime, that it means, I click a button and `sap.m.Input` fields will be auto generated and it places in **SimpleForm** control.

[image]

Calling `SimpleForm` with by **id**, the control can be found:

[image]

The fragment:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/Dialog",
    "sap/m/Text",
    "sap/m/Button"
], function (Dialog, Text, Button) {
    "use strict";

    const fnNumList = () => {
        return new sap.m.ObjectListItem({
            number: "{ValueHelp>NumValueFrom}",
            numberUnit: "{ValueHelp>UnitOfMeasurement}"
        });
    };

    const fnCharList = () => {
        return new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            description: "{ValueHelp>CharValue}"
        });
    };

    const fnCurrList = () => {
        return new sap.m.ObjectListItem({
            number: "{ValueHelp>CurrValueFrom}",
            numberUnit: "{ValueHelp>CurrCurrencyFrom}"
        });
    };

    const fnDateList = () => {

        const oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({
            dateValue: "{ValueHelp>DateValueFrom}",
            valueFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            editable: false
        });

        return new sap.m.CustomListItem({
            content: oDatePicker
        });
    };

    const fnTimeList = () => {
        const oTimePicker = new sap.m.TimePicker({
            valueFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            displayFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            support2400: true,
            dateValue: "{ValueHelp>TimeValueFrom}",
            editable: false
        });

        return new sap.m.CustomListItem({
            content: oTimePicker
        });
    };

    const fnDetermineListType = (oValueHelp) => {
        switch (oValueHelp.DataType) {
        case "NUM":
            return fnNumList();
        case "DATE":
            return fnDateList();
        case "TIME":
            return fnTimeList;
        case "CURR":
            return fnCurrList();
        default:
            return fnCharList();
        }
    };

    const fnCreateList = (oValueHelp) => {
        const oNewList = new sap.m.List({
            includeItemInSelection: true,
            mode: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelect
        });

        oNewList.bindItems({
            path: "ValueHelp>/",
            template: fnDetermineListType(oValueHelp)
        });

        return oNewList;
    };

    const fnDestroyDialog = (oDialog) => {
        oDialog.close();
        oDialog.destroy();
    };

    return {

        showSingle: function (aCharsHelpValues, fnGetSelectedObject, sValueHelpField) {
            const oList = fnCreateList(aCharsHelpValues[0]);
            const oDialog = new Dialog({
                title: aCharsHelpValues[0].CharValue,
                content: oList,
                beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "OK",
                    press: function () {
                        fnGetSelectedObject(oList.getSelectedItem().getBindingContext("ValueHelp").getObject(), sValueHelpField);
                        fnDestroyDialog(oDialog);
                    }
                }),
                endButton: new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Close",
                    press: function () {
                        fnDestroyDialog(oDialog);
                    }
                })
            });

            return oDialog;
        }
    };

});
```

**Update**
The input is generated with:

```
    _buildCharacInputId: function (oData) {
        return "CharInput:" + oData.Classtype + ":" + oData.Classnum + ":" + oData.NameChar;
    },

_determineCtrlForChars: function (oData) {
            const sId = this._buildCharacInputId(oData);
            const self = this;
            switch (oData.DataType) {
            case "CHAR":
                return new sap.m.Input(sId, {
                    maxLength: oData.NumberDigits,
                    type: sap.m.InputType.Text,
                    showValueHelp: oData.WithValues,
                    valueHelpRequest: self._onCharValueHelp.bind(self)
                });
            case "CURR":
                return new sap.m.MaskInput(sId, {
                    mask: oData.Template.replace(/_/g, "9") + (oData.Currency ? " ".concat(oData.Currency) : "")
                });
            case "DATE":
                return new sap.m.DatePicker(sId, {
                    valueFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
                    displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy"
                });
            case "NUM":
                return new sap.m.MaskInput(sId, {
                    mask: oData.Template.replace(/_/g, "9") + (oData.UnitTExt ? " ".concat(oData.UnitTExt) : "")
                });
            case "TIME":
                return new sap.m.TimePicker(sId, {
                    valueFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                    displayFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                    support2400: true
                });
            default:
                throw "Not supported type. Please contact app developer.";
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is not generated in the `View` scope, so it will not have the proper DOM id.

The following code in your controller creates an id like `CharInput-001-ZPM_TEST_01-ZPM_TEST_5`:

```
_buildCharacInputId: function (oData) {
    return "CharInput:" + oData.Classtype + ":" + oData.Classnum + ":" + oData.NameChar;
},
//...
const sId = this._buildCharacInputId(oData);
```

Using [`createId()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller/methods/createId) will prefix the view, so that the id is `__xmlview1--CharInput-001-ZPM_TEST_01-ZPM_TEST_5`:

```
//...
const sId = this.createId(this._buildCharacInputId(oData));
```